# Would it be possible to use SMTP Sampler without providing attachment?

Tags: jmeter, smtp

I would like to use SMTP Sampler in my Jmter script but i am getting error 500 saying that a file location is access denied. I performed workaround by adding attachment but in my case, I do not need to attach any files for my SMTP sampler. Are there any workaround for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Double check that there is no [whitespaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitespace_character) in the "Attach file(s)" input (the whitespaces are not visible but given you provide something there JMeter will try to load the file)

You can open your .jmx script with a text/XML editor of your choice (JMeter .jmx scripts are basically [XML files](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/))

If you don't want to send any attachments there should be the following line in the script:

```
<stringProp name="SMTPSampler.attachFile"></stringProp>
```

if there are any characters between `attachFile">` and `</stringProp>` - remove them and your request should start working (assuming that other configuration parameters are correct)

An example of incorrect setup (with 3 whitespaces) will look like:

[image]

Check out [Load Testing Your Email Server: How to Send and Receive E-mails with JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/load-testing-your-email-server-how-send-and-receive-e-mails-jmeter/) article where you can see example configuration which you can re-use for building your own request.

Answer (score 0):

You can check [Send plain body](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#SMTP_Sampler) and put your message text inside the file,

> Send plain body (i.e. not multipart/mixed) If selected, then send the body as a plain message, i.e. not multipart/mixed, if possible. If the message body is empty and there is a single file, then send the file contents as the message body.

Email will send file content as email body

Comment: Apologies,but what i meant is that i dont want to add attachment in the smtp sampler. tried to send plain body without attachment and still get the same error

Comment: @Vegil this is what I answer *If the message body is empty and there is a single file, then send the file contents as the message body*